# Risk function of an estimator under zero-one loss / evaluating an integral with an indicator.

Tags: integration, statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I am working through some questions concerning the risk function of maximum likelihood estimators under zero-one loss, and am struggling with the evaluation of what seems like a simple integral.

**Problem.**

Let $X_1, ..., X_n \sim N(\theta, 1)$. Suppose that $\theta \in \{-1, 1\}$.

Find the risk function of the maximum likelihood estimator $\tilde{\theta}$ under zero-one loss:

$$L(\theta, \widehat{\theta}) =
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if} \space \theta \neq \widehat{\theta} \\
0 &\text{if} \space \theta = \widehat{\theta} \\
\end{cases}$$

**My attempt.**

The maximum likelihood estimator $\tilde{\theta}$ here is just the sample mean $\overline{X}_n$. I used the fact that for a given estimator $\hat{\theta}$, the risk function $R(\cdot, \hat{\theta})$ is the expectation of the loss function with respect to the joint distribution of the data $X_1, ..., X_n$. And I am aware that I should get a function of the form $R: \Theta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, where in this case, $\Theta$ is the restricted parameter space $\{-1, 1\}$. And so I have:

$$\begin{align}
R(\theta, \tilde{\theta}) &= \mathbb{E}_{\theta}[L(\theta, \tilde{\theta})] \\
&= \int ... \int L(\theta, \widehat{\theta}) f_{X_1, ..., X_n}(x_1, ..., x_n; \theta) dx_1 ... dx_n \\
&= \int ... \int \mathbb{I}(\theta \neq \bar{X}_n) (2\pi)^{-n/2}\exp \left(\frac{1}{2}\sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - \theta)^2 \right) dx_1 ... dx_n
\end{align}$$

However, I am having difficulty evaluating this integral. I would appreciate some assistance on this.

**Related questions on stackexchange.**

The most similar question to mine I could find on any of the stackexchange forums was one [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201353/calculating-the-risk-of-an-estimator-using-zero-one-loss), however, in that case, it is for discrete rather than continuous rvs, so it's more obvious how to compute the risk function.

Comment: Are you sure you should use the sample mean? Should your estimate not be a value in the parameter space $\{-1, 1\}$?

Comment: @Dasherman Now you frame it that way, the sample mean would be a valid estimator if the parameter space was *not* restricted, but I'm guessing that now is no longer the case given the restrictions. Now I've had time to articulate what it is that is bothering me about this.  I am now unsure about what my mle should be. I initially thought it should be $\widehat{\theta} = -1$, but a few calculations I've done are currently suggesting to me that the mle under this particular restricted parameter space is dependent on the sign of the majority of the data. Should I try and formalise this?

Comment: Find the likelihood $L(\theta)$ at each of the points $\theta=-1$ and $\theta=1$. So if $L(-1)>L(1)$, then MLE is $\hat\theta=-1$ and if $L(-1)<L(1)$ then MLE is $\hat\theta=1$. There are no difficult integrals in this problem. You just have to express the condition $L(-1)>L(1)$ or $L(-1)<L(1)$ in terms of the sample.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, thank you for the further prompt.

Comment: @StubbornAtom. I revisited question after having left it, and was drafting up an answer having thought I solved it. Using what you said, I found the MLE to be: $$\hat{\theta}_n = \begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{if} \quad \bar{X}_n > 0 \\ -1 \quad \text{if} \quad \bar{X}_n < 0 \end{cases}$$, but a small issue is what happens when $\bar{X}_n = 0$. Do we break ties arbitrarily, or is the estimator undefined in this case? This is preventing me from computing the risk function.

Comment: When $\overline X_n=0$, either value of $\theta$ could be MLE. But $P(\overline X_n=0)=0$, so need not worry about this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to helpful comments by [StubbornAtom](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/321264/stubbornatom) and [Dasherman](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/177453/dasherman), the following is a verbose solution transcribed from my write-up.

**Computing the maximum likelihood estimator $\tilde{\theta}$ when the parameter space $\Theta = \{-1, 1\}$ is restricted.**

The likelihood function is

$$L(\theta) = \prod^n_{i=1} f_{X_i}(x_i; \theta) = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2 \pi})^n} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} \sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - \theta)^2 \right)$$

Therefore the log-likelihood function is

$$l(\theta) = -n \log \sqrt{2 \pi} - \frac{1}{2} \sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - \theta)^2$$

For the possible values of the 'true' parameter $\theta_0 = -1$ and $\theta_1 = 1$, and without loss of generality, maximisation of the log-likelihood $l(\theta)$ amounts to ascertaining conditions under which

$$l(\theta_0) > l(\theta_1)$$

Using the 'trick' that we can express the summation in $l(\theta)$ in the following way:

$$\sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - \theta)^2 = \sum^n_{i=1} [ (x_i - \overline{x}_n)^2 + (\overline{x}_n - \theta)^2 ] = n(\overline{x}_n - \theta)^2 + \sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - \overline{x}_n)^2$$

Our inequality $l(\theta_0) > l(\theta_1)$ can now be expressed as:

$$\begin{align}
-n \log \sqrt{2 \pi} + n (\overline{x}_n + 1)^2 - \frac{1}{2} \sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - \overline{x}_n)^2 > &\space -n \log \sqrt{2 \pi} + n (\overline{x}_n - 1)^2 \\
& \space - \frac{1}{2} \sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - \overline{x}_n)^2
\end{align}$$

Simplifying this we have that:

$$n(\overline{x}_n + 1)^2 < n(\overline{x}_n - 1)^2$$

And solving this gives

$$\overline{x}_n < 0$$

We can make sense of this as saying that the likelihood is maximised by setting $\theta = \theta_0 = -1$ when the sample mean $\overline{X}_n < 0$. And similarly, when the sample mean $\overline{X}_n > 0$, then we can maximise the likelihood by setting $\theta = \theta_1 = 1$. Hence the maximum likelihood estimator is

$$
\tilde{\theta}(X_1, \dots, X_n) =
\begin{cases}
1 \quad &\text{if} \quad \overline{X}_n > 0 \\
-1 \quad &\text{if} \quad \overline{X}_n < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Intuitively, this means that if we use the maximum likelihood principle as a criterion for selecting an estimator $\tilde{\theta}$, then if the central tendency of the data, as estimated by the sample mean $\overline{X}_n$ lies in the interval $(0, \infty)$, then it is more plausible that the 'true' parameter that generated under the distribution $N(\theta, 1)$ is $\theta = 1$. And a similar argument holds that $\theta = -1$ for when $\overline{X}_n$ is in the interval $(-\infty, 0)$.

That the above maximum likelihood estimator is undefined for when $\overline{X}_n = 0$, means that it is not possible to say according to the maximum likelihood principle whether it is $\theta = 1$ or $\theta = -1$ that generated the data.

**Computing the risk function $R(\theta, \tilde{\theta})$ of the maximum likelihood estimator $\tilde{\theta}$.**

Using the notation that $x^n$ stands for the observed data $X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_n = x_n$, the risk function $R(\theta, \hat{\theta})$ of an arbitrary estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is the expectation of the loss $L(\theta, \hat{\theta})$ with respect to the distribution $p(x^n ; \theta)$ that generated the data:

$$R(\theta, \hat{\theta}) = \mathbb{E}_{p(x^n; \theta)}[L(\theta, \hat{\theta})] = \int L(\theta, \hat{\theta}(x^n)) \cdot p(x^n ; \theta) \space d x^n$$

Which is a function(al) of the parameter $\theta$ and the estimator $\hat{\theta}$.

We now rewrite the piecewise zero-one loss function in terms of indicators:

$$
L(\theta, \hat{\theta}) = 
\begin{cases}
1 \quad &\text{if} \quad \theta \neq \hat{\theta} \\
0 \quad &\text{if} \quad \theta = \hat{\theta} \\
\end{cases}
= 1 - \mathbb{I}(\hat{\theta} = \theta)
$$

Meaning that the risk function is:

$$R(\theta, \hat{\theta}) = \int [1 - \mathbb{I}(\hat{\theta}(x^n) = \theta)] \cdot p(x^n ; \theta) \space dx^n = 1 - \int \mathbb{I}(\hat{\theta}(x^n) = \theta)] \cdot p(x^n ; \theta) \space dx^n$$

If we suppress the dependence of the maximum likelihood estimator $\tilde{\theta}(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ on the data, and instead view it as some random variable $Y = \tilde{\theta}(X_1, \dots, X_n)$, then it is a discrete random variable similar to a Bernoulli random variable, except that $Y$ has realisations $1$ and $-1$. The probability mass function of $Y$ is now

$$
f_{Y}(y) = 
\begin{cases}
1 - p \quad &\text{if} \quad y = 1 \\
p \quad &\text{if} \quad y = -1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

where the parameter $p = P(\overline{X}_n < 0)$ and $1 - p = P(\overline{X}_n > 0)$, which needs to be evaluated.

In order to compute the parameter $p$, for normally distributed $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, we have that the sample mean $\overline{X}_n$ will also be normally distributed, $\overline{X}_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2 / n)$. Because $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(\theta, 1)$, we can apply standard calculations to get

$$p = P(\overline{X}_n < 0) = P \left(Z < \frac{-\theta}{\sqrt{1 / n}}\right) = P(Z < -\theta \sqrt{n}) = \Phi(-\theta \sqrt{n})$$

where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function. The probability mass function of $Y$ is therefore

$$
f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
1 - \Phi(-\theta \sqrt{n}) \quad &\text{if} \quad y = 1 \\
\Phi(-\theta \sqrt{n}) \quad &\text{if} \quad y = -1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Using the fact that for some random variable $X$ and set $A$, $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}(X \in A)] = P(X \in A)$, the risk function evaluated using the maximum likelihood estimator $\tilde{\theta}$ in terms of the above probability mass function is:

$$R(\theta, \tilde{\theta}) = 1 - \mathbb{E}_{p(\tilde{\theta} ; \space p)}[\mathbb{I}(\tilde{\theta} = \theta)] = 1 - P(\tilde{\theta} = \theta) = 1 - f_{Y}(\theta)$$

Therefore the risk function for the maximum likelihood estimator is:

$$
R(\theta, \tilde{\theta}) = 
\begin{cases}
\Phi(- \sqrt{n}) \quad &\text{if} \quad \theta = 1 \\
1 - \Phi(\sqrt{n}) \quad &\text{if} \quad \theta = -1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: @StubbornAtom. Using your helpful comments, I managed to compute the MLE and am confident that it is correct. However, I am unsure whether the reasoning behind my evaluation of the risk function is correct. Would you mind letting me know your thoughts on it? If it is incorrect then I will have another stab and edit my answer so others self-studying who might similarly struggle may benefit,. However, if you think it looks fine do say so and I will mark as accepted and close the matter.

Comment: I think defining $Y$ is unnecessary. The risk is simply $R(\theta,\tilde\theta)=P_{\theta}(\tilde\theta\ne \theta)$ for $\theta\in \{-1,1\}$. When $\theta=-1$, it is $P_{\theta=-1}(\overline X_n>0)$ and when $\theta=1$, it is $P_{\theta=1}(\overline X_n<0)$. I get the same answer as you do.

Comment: @StubbornAtom. Thank you for your patient assistance with this question.